# How to get system long date using mfc?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I need to get system current long date using MFC. My requirement is I need to get the system long date without format. For example: In my system if the date sets in "dd/mm/yyyy" format then I need to get in same format.

Suppose in my system if I change the format as "yyyy/mm/dd" then I need to get the output as what ever I sets in my system.

I found `DATE_SHORTDATE` is getting the date as it is how the system displays, if I use `DATE_LONGDATE` it will always gets the system date in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format

```
CString strValue;
SYSTEMTIME st;
CTime time = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
time.GetAsSystemTime(st);
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_SHORTDATE, &st, NULL, strValue.GetBufferSetLength(50), 50);

strValue.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Kindly assist me on this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns the correct value, however using 'mm' string is not supported by some of the locales in LongDate format.

On my Windows 10 1903, English-US locale, the control panel overrides the 'mm' value to 'MM'.

[image: Control Panel],

More reference regarding LongDatePattern:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longdatepattern?view=netframework-4.8